# Global planner path update faster

Tags: ros, path, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how do i make the global planner realize that its path is blocked by an obstacle and re-update faster ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236502/global-planner-path-update-faster/) by [rajnunes](https://answers.ros.org/users/26472/rajnunes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is a very generic question, actually not related to ROS (unless you are talking about an specific ROS package), but I will try to answer it anyway.

Basically, you have to periodically run collision checking on your path, and if the path is not longer valid, recalculate. Depending on the algorithm and your specific problem, you can do this in many many different ways. For example, if you are able to detect what changed in the map, you only have to evaluate if the path goes through those places with changes. Or if the robot is moving along the path, you do not need to check the whole path, just the remaining part. Or if you use a planner like elastic bands or something, it will automatically update to avoid collisions.

At the end, it really depends on what you are using and your problem statement.

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2016-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rajnunes](https://answers.ros.org/users/26472/rajnunes/) on 2016-06-09**:
We are already using teb_local planner but .. the global planner does not realize that there is a obstacle (at least i think it does not realize ) in its way until the local planner (i mean the bot base frame ) gets too close to an obstacle...only then does the global planner re route after a while

**Comment by [FOXTER](https://answers.ros.org/users/26976/foxter/) on 2016-06-09**:
If you are using the move_base node, there is the "planner_frequency" parameter which determines the frequency which the global planner runs at. If you increase the value the global plan will update more often.

**Comment by [FOXTER](https://answers.ros.org/users/26976/foxter/) on 2016-06-09**:
You can also increase the "obstacle_range" parameter for the costmaps which is the maximum distance where obstacles are added.